# Pagination on "get_term_children" - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, pager, taxonomy-terms

I would like to get a pager in my page, can i create a pager with a for each  or while without parameter like "posts_per_page" ?

I get term children of my taxonomy and i would like to display 3 by 3

My code :

> ```
>       $childGalerie = get_term_children(15,'wpmf-category');
>
>       foreach ( $childGalerie as $oneGalerie ) : 
>        $maGalerie = get_term($oneGalerie, 'wpmf-category');
>
>        ?>
>        <h2 class="info-galerie"><span></span><?php echo $maGalerie->name;  > </h2>
>        <div class="galerie-photo">
>            <?php
>            global $post;
>            $args = array(
>                'posts_per_page'   => -1,
>                'post_type'        => 'attachment',
>                //                    'post_status'      => 'inherit',
>                'tax_query' => array(
>                    array(
>                        'taxonomy' => 'wpmf-category',
>                        'field' => 'term_id',
>                        'terms' => $oneGalerie
>                    ),
>                ),
>            );
>            $media = get_posts( $args );
>            foreach ( $media as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); 
>            ?>
>            <div class="wrapper-galerie">
>                <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $media->ID, 'galerie->photo' ); ?>
>            </div>
>            <?php
>            endforeach; 
>            wp_reset_postdata();
>
>            ?>
>        </div>
>        <?php
>        endforeach;
> ```

Can you help me please , ty :D